# Calculating time difference of every other row from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Note:** *The data for my question is on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e4e4d/1) right here where you
>   can query it.*

### How the table is created

I have data from a table and put into a temp table using the below logic but the `BETWEEN` start and end date time stamps are dynamically generated based on other logic in the stored proc, etc.

```
SET @RowNum = 0;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS

SELECT @RowNum := @RowNum + 1 RowNum
        , TimeStr
        , Value        
FROM mytable     
WHERE TimeStr BETWEEN '2018-01-31 06:15:56' AND '2018-01-31 19:27:09'
AND iQuality = 3 ORDER BY TimeStr;
```

This gives me a temp table with the row number which increments up one number in order starting with the oldest based `TimeStr` records, so the oldest is the time of the first record or `RowNum` 1.

> **Temp Table**
>
> [image]

---

### The Data

You can get to this temp table data and play with the queries here on the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e4e4d/1) I've created but I have a few things I tried there you'll see there which don't give me what I need though.

### Attempt to Clarify Further

I need to get the time for each **ON** and **OFF** set based on the `TimeStr` values in each set and I can get this using the [TIMEDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make it give me the result of each **ON** and **OFF** record. The records are always in order from oldest to newest and the row number always starts at 1 too.

I some how need to give give every two records with one after the other  `RowNum` values wise a matching `CycleNum` starting at 1 and increment by one per each **ON** and **OFF** cycle or set.

I can use `TIMEDIFF(MAX(TimeStr), MIN(TimeStr)) as duration` but I'm not sure how to best get it to group every two `RowNum` records in order as explained to give each set a subsequent `CycleNum` value that increments.

---

### Expected Output

The expected output show look like the below screen shot for all **ON** and **OFF** cycles or every two `RowNum` in groups and sequence.

[image]

### Output Clarification

I need the output to include each **ON** and **OFF** cycle's start time, end time, and the duration for the time between the start and stop.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler one :

```
SELECT
  t1.TimeStr AS StartTime, 
  t2.TimeStr AS EndTime, 
  TIMEDIFF(t2.TimeStr, t1.TimeStr) AS Duration  
FROM temp t1
INNER JOIN temp t2 ON t2.RowNum = t1.RowNum + 1
WHERE 
    t2.Value = 0
AND t1.Value = 1
```

Comment: @BitcoinMurderousManiac As they said, All Roads Lead to Rome. at least you got what you're digging for ;)

Comment: @BitcoinMurderousManiac Gordon's cross join is easy to understand if you know what he is doing; he is using it as an in-query SET statement, so that two separate queries are not needed. Notice this answer leaves out the cyclenum you were wanting.

Comment: @BitcoinMurderousManiac No need to apologize. I wasn't criticizing, just explaining. ...and, yeah, I've run into that temporary table issue before myself; sometimes I just create the "temp" table as a normal table and make sure to drop it after (but the feasibility of that option greatly depends on circumstances).

Answer (score 3):

If you can guarantee two things:

- That the row numbers are strictly sequential with no gaps.
- That the on/off flag is always alternating.

Then you can do this with a relatively simple `join`.  The code looks like:

```
SELECT (@rn := @rn + 1) as cycle, t.*, tnext.timestr,
       timediff(tnext.timestr, t.timestr)
FROM temp t JOIN
     temp tnext
     ON t.rownum = tnext.rownum - 1 and
        t.value = 1 and
        tnext.value = 0 cross join
     (SELECT @rn := 0) params;
```

If these conditions are not true, then more complex logic is needed.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to do it would be this:

```
SELECT 
  T1.TimeStr AS StartTime, 
  (SELECT T2.TimeStr FROM temp AS T2 WHERE T2.RowNum = T1.RowNum+1) AS StopTime,
  TIMEDIFF((SELECT T2.TimeStr FROM temp AS T2 WHERE T2.RowNum = T1.RowNum+1),
           T1.TimeStr) AS Duration
FROM temp AS T1
WHERE Value = 1;
```

Seems like there must be better ways to do this. Two subqueries will be slow.

You could do it in two steps:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE startstop AS
SELECT 
  T1.TimeStr AS StartTime, 
  (SELECT T2.TimeStr FROM temp AS T2 WHERE T2.RowNum = T1.RowNum+1) AS StopTime,
  0 AS Duration
FROM temp AS T1
WHERE Value = 1;

UPDATE startstop SET Duration = StopTime - StartTime;
```

However I cannot test this in the Fiddle.